# RestTemaple Post Call exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write
>   request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type
>   [com.guestbook.model.Routine]

```
Im getting above exception while making POST call
```

Im getting above exception while making POST call
 Im getting above exception while making POST call

Code:

```
Routine routine= new Routine();
routine.setDate(Routine.getDate());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        System.out.println(URLConstants.routine);
        Routine r=restTemplate.postForObject(URLConstants.routine, routine, Routine.class);
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.guestbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>guestbook-webapp</artifactId>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>google-staging</id>
            <name>Google Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgoogleappengine-1004/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.0</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.framework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your object with `HttpEntity`, e.g., `HttpEntity<Routine> request = new HttpEntity<>(routine);` and then post the entity: `restTemplate.postForObject(URLConstants.routine, request, Routine.class);`

Comment: I tried this too..but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

- Remove all Spring and Jackson dependencies
- Define `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent for your POM
- Include `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-test` dependencies (without versions defined!!!)

Example of such configuration is available in any web tailored [Spring Guide Guide](https://spring.io/guides). E.g. [REST one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

[Here is example of such POM file](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/blob/master/complete/pom.xml).

Comment: Its not spring boot application..still i can go ahead?

Comment: So why the question is having `spring-boot` tag?

Comment: BTW, if you can, migrate to Spring Boot. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Actually this is GAE application..GAE goole app engine not supporting spring boot..so struck with this...Im hosting this app on cloud for free through GAE...but GAE not supporting spring boot, so Im gng with previous spring versions

Comment: Solved,,problem with jackson dependecy..i had added more same dependency thrice with different versions..so its not taking ..I put only 1 dependency with required version..Now able to download that depedency..Issue solved